# Attempt to index a new value

Tags: roblox

ok, i am trying to execute a script, but it is always giving an error: "attempt to index a nil value"

I already tried using

```
game.Players.crift_games1:GetMouse().Keydown:connect(k)
        if k == "z" and...
```

But the code i am using is: (crift_games1 is my name)

```
plr = game.Players.crift_games1
mouse = plr:GetMouse()

mouse.KeyDown:connect(function(k)
        if k == "z" and attack == false then
                Move2()
        end
        if k == "x" and attack == false then
                Move1()
        end
        if k == "c" and attack == false then
                Move3()
        end
end)
```

expected output:

actual output: attempt to index a new value

Comment: What script? Explain better what are you doing, what is your problem and you have tried to resolve it.

Comment: i am trying to create an attack script, the move1, move2 and move3 functions is working correctly, but the function that detects the key you clicked does not work, so can you help me

Answer (score 0):

before I get into everything make sure that the keydown script is a localscript.

I would like to first start off by saying .KeyDown is not the recommended so instead we will use UserInputService.

```lua
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local attack = false
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Z and attack == false then
        Move2()
    end
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.X and attack == false then
        Move1()
    end
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.C and attack == false then
        Move3()
    end
end)
```